# How to avoid automatic data formatting of Big Number in Excel

Tags: java

I am running a Spring Batch job to generate a CSV file having some customer information. When file generates customer's phone number is listed as `322857260002`; upon opening up the file, you'll have the number shown as `3.22858E+11`. I want to see the complete number in file(`322857260002`)

```
unmatchedItem.setMpsReference(rs.getString("MPS_REFENRECE"));
```

**mpsReferenceNumber** is as String in the **UnmatchedItem** object. I have tried BigInteger also but the issue still remains.

Please help me and let me know in case if you  need more information.

Regards

Comment: What does this have to do with Java, String, Spring-MVC ***or*** biginteger? The value is coming from a CSV file?

Comment: Can I use some data type so I can stop formatting

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies with Excel, not with your CSV file. Try changing the format of the offending cells to a specific numeric format.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read it to convert from double to Bigdecimal.

```
if XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
Double doubleValue = nextCell.getNumericCellValue();
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(doubleValue.toString());
```